# What does it mean when Spark executor results are "sent via BlockManager"?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, containers

I have a host running a spark-master along with 3 spark-workers, all in docker containers. I have another host acting as a Spark-driver, reading data from the first host.

I am able to successfully retrieve data from the first host as long as the data returned is tiny (<6000 rows)
But it's failing when I'm trying to read large blocks (100k+ rows).

I checked the executor logs and when the reads are successful, I'm getting this following log message:

```
19/07/23 21:54:17 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: DataMonitor
19/07/23 21:54:17 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4). 1014673 bytes result sent to driver
19/07/23 21:54:24 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: DataMonitor
```

But when the reads are unsuccessful, I'm getting this following log message:

```
19/07/23 22:21:55 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: DataMonitor
19/07/23 22:22:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block taskresult_13 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 119.2 MB, free 2.4 GB)
19/07/23 22:22:03 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 13). 124969484 bytes result sent via BlockManager)
19/07/23 22:22:10 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: DataMonitor
```

It looks like when the results are large enough, it gets "sent via BlockManager"
But when it's small enough, it gets "sent to the driver".

So how do I get it so every results are sent to the driver?

Comment: Could you please try the below options 1. Increase number of executors, bases on the cores available on the host . 2. Increase number of tasks. 3. Increase of CPU cores per task. This way we can share the load of the data.

Comment: Could you share error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Executor runs tasks and sends the result of the task back to the driver.
If a task result is small, it sends it directly with task status, but if the result size is big, calculated by the following formula:

```
taskResultSize > conf.getSizeAsBytes("spark.task.maxDirectResultSize", 1L << 20)
```

or

```
taskResultSize > conf.get("spark.driver.maxResultSize")
```

[source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L166)

Executor stores the result on disk locally and sends [IndirectTaskResult](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L526) with `blockId` back to the driver.

Then driver uses netty via `BlockManager` to download the remote result.
[Take a look here.](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskResultGetter.scala#L82)

If it is not detailed enough, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Increased the "spark.task.maxDirectResultSize" to 2g+ solved my problem. Everything is being sent back directly to the driver in a timely manner now.